# A proper way to work with MVC

Tags: mvc, mvp

I got into a debate at work today, I hope you can help me to settle it up.

My colleague wants to separate UI, Model, DB, and Network like so:

- Create an API level between UI and controller, that will allow the UI
  to query **all** the models in the APP.
- There will be another controller that will break the models into
  their DB representations (Ex: UserTablesModel, ScoreTableModel...),
  It will be a singleton called DBControler and it will
  also provide some utility methods to query the DB (Ex:
  insert(tableName, value...).
- The ModelTables will use events hub to notify UI with state changes,
  and they will be updated from the network layer using DBControler
  reference.

I don't like this idea as it creates a coupling between unrelated models in the controller layer. I think it would be wiser to allow the UI to have direct access to Models (maybe make them singletons) and it's up to the model to offer a proper API to access its data and provide an events callback to notify his state change (no events hub). I like the part that models need to be directly updated from the network layer.

Also I don't like the name TableModel, I think the DB needs to be a service accessible by the model, one model can access multiple tables.

What is the proper way to work with MVC?

Comment: Things you never see in a software department: One developer looks at another's code and says "I'd have done it *exactly* the same way!"

Comment: @RobbieDee tnx Robbie, it's very funny what you just say, it also might be true and interesting. How ever I am seeking for more professional and meaningful answers.

Answer (score 3):

I'd seriously recommend looking into **viewmodels**. How the data is presented in the database isn't always how you'd want it presented in the UI.

A common example is prices - where it might be stored as an int or decimal in the DB. However, in the UI, you'd maybe want the currency symbol and digit grouping so:

$1,999 rather than 1999.

Adding this logic to the UI or model makes no sense - and with a viewmodel, the UI & model can be kept clean: the UI just serves up the data, the viewmodel only contains the data and logic required, and the model stores the initial representation of the data.

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) describes its use in ASP.NET MVC, but the general principles are sound.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Knockoutjs(simplyfy dynamic Javascript UIs), Model View-View Model(MVVM) architecture pattern.

Usually in MVC pattern, Model will hold all data, View is for UIs, and Controller will connect UI and Model.

In MVVM pattern, Model-View will display data from your database, View-Model will hold data temporarily based on UI input, once submit or save, Controller now do its work to validate and save it to your Database.

Analogy: 1. I give you candy and you hold it in your hands (MVVM) but you can
            return it to me, loop..
         2. If you eat it, and its done (Controller)

Comment: try this link,  www.knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html